# awk to check order of header line in text files

Tags: bash, awk

In the `bash` below I am trying to use `awk` to verify that the order of the `headers` is exactly the same between the `tab-delimited` files (`key` has the order of fields and `text files`, usually 3 in a directory).

If the order is correct or matches are found between the files, then `print FILENAME` has the expected order of fields, but if the order does not match between the files, then `print FILENAME` causes "the order of $i is not correct", where `$i` is the field out of order using `key` as the order.  Thank you :)

**key**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref Alt Inheritance Score
```

**file1.txt**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref Alt Inheritance Score
1   1   10  100 A   -   .   2
```

**file2.txt**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref Alt Inheritance
1   1   10  100 A   -   .   2
2   1   20  100 A   -   .   5
```

**file3.txt**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref Alt Inheritance
1   1   10  100 A   -   .   2
2   1   20  100 A   -   .   5
3   1   75  100 A   -   .   2
4   1   25  100 A   -   .   5
```

**awk**

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/validate/*.txt ; do
bname=`basename $f`
 awk '
  FNR==NR {
   order=(awk '!seen[$0]++ {lines[i++]=$0}
    END {for (i in lines) if (seen[lines[i]]==1) print lines[i]})'
       k=(awk '!seen[$0]++ {lines[i++]=$0}
    END {for (i in lines) if (seen[lines[i]]==1) print lines[i]})'
        if($order==$k) print FILENAME " has expected order of fields"
        else
        print FILENAME " order of $i is not correct"
}' key $f
done
```

**desired output**

```
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/validate/file1.txt has expected order of fields
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/validate/file2.txt order of Score is not correct
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/validate/file3.txt order of Score is not correct
```

Comment: are all the files have only one line?

Comment: No sorry there are multiple lines in each text file, the length can vary.... I will update the post., however the header line is always 1 in text file each file.  The `key` is only 1 line.  Thank you :).

Comment: You are confusing awk with shell. **Awk is not shell**. You can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given those input, you can do something like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hn=split($0,header); next} 
     FNR==1 {n=split($0,fh)
            for(i=1;i<=hn; i++)
                if (fh[i]!=header[i]) {
                    printf "%s: order of %s is not correct\n" ,FILENAME, header[i]
                    next}
            if (hn==n)
                print FILENAME, "has expected order of fields"
            else
                print FILENAME, "has extra fields"  
                next              
                }' key f{1..3}
```

Prints:

```
f1 has expected order of fields
f2 order of Score is not correct
f3 order of Score is not correct
```

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { split($0,keys); next }
FNR==1 {
    allmatched = 1
    for (i=1; i in keys; i++) {
        if ($i != keys[i] ) {
            printf "%s order of %s is not correct\n", FILENAME, keys[i]
            allmatched = 0
        }
    }
    if ( allmatched ) {
        printf "%s has expected order of fields\n", FILENAME
    }
    nextfile
}

$ awk -f tst.awk key file1 file2 file3
file1 has expected order of fields
file2 order of Score is not correct
file3 order of Score is not correct
```

The above uses GNU awk for `nextfile` for efficiency. With other awks just delete that statement and accept the whole of each file will be read.

You didn't include in your sample a case where a header appears in a file but was NOT present in keys so I assume that can't happen and so you don't need the script to handle it.

Comment: I am learning awk and reading Effective Awk Programming and it is helping, but theres a lot :), not too mention his great book on shell. Thank you :).